# PDO не удаляются данные из бд, Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]:

Tags: php, pdo

Ошибка: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.product' doesn't exist in C:\OpenServer\domains\test\delete.php:70 Stack trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\test\delete.php(70): PDO->query('DELETE FROM pro...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\test\delete.php on line 70`
Отрывок кода

```
 }
            if ($part == "go") //если пользователь подтвердил удаление:
            {
//подключаемся к СУБД MsSQL
                $db = Db::getConnection();
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                if ($table == "proizv") //если удаляет поставщика – удаляем также все записи о товарах, связанные с ним
                {
//сначала удаляем товары
                    $sql = 'SELECT idp FROM produkt WHERE idpr = \'' . $id . '\' LIMIT 0, 1000';
                    $result = $db->query($sql);
                    $num = $result->rowCount();
                    if ($num != 0) {
                        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
                            $sql = 'DELETE FROM produkt WHERE idp = \'' . $row[0] . '\' LIMIT 1';
                            $res = $db->query($sql);
                        };
                    }
//освобаждаем результаты запросов
//затем удалем запись о поставщике
                    $sql = 'DELETE FROM proizv WHERE idpr = \'' . $id . '\' LIMIT 1';
                    $result = $db->query($sql);
                } else //если удаляет не поставщика
                {
//строим запрос на удаление выбранной записи
                    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE ' . $pole . ' = \'' . $id . '\' LIMIT 1';
//выполняем запрос
                    $result = $db->query($sql);
                }
//ввыводим сообщение о том, что запись удалена
                echo '<h2 style = "color : red">Запись удалена</h2>';
            }
            ?>
```

line 67-70 -

```
//строим запрос на удаление выбранной записи
                    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE ' . $pole . ' = \'' . $id . '\' LIMIT 1';
//выполняем запрос
                    $result = $db->query($sql);
```

структура таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: product - produkt ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, никогда не составляйте SQL-запросы склеиванием различных строк. Это приводит к [уязвимостям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внедрение_SQL-кода). Используйте [подготовленные запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) с параметрами. По последней ссылке изучите примеры с bindParam методом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я сам не понимаю, откуда взялся "product "

Comment: @TRIGGERED ну в переменную он же не из ниоткуда попадает?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский            ` $table = $_GET['table'];`

Comment: Ну вот. А говорите не понимаете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что в переменной `$table` некорректно задано имя таблицы.

А ещё, надеюсь оно проходит через белый список разрешённых имён? Иначе SQL инъекции не миновать. Хотя её итак не миновать. потому что вы не пользуетесь подготовленными запросами (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)